# Get value automatically after input in one field in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a usd to inr converter but the problem is when i input in one field it doesn't automatically convert in another field.I tried using onblur but it didn't work only when i use my keys to increment or decrement as number field it is working.I don't know what is causing only keyups and downs to work .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Currency Converter in Javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br><br>
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">Currency Converter</h1>
            <form id="myForm">
                <br><br>
                <label for="Base Currency">Base Currency</label>

                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="baseNumber" value="1" onblur="curr()">
                </div>
                <label for="Target Currency">Target Currency</label>
 
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input  class="form-control" id="targetNumber">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I want the result to be automatically displayed in another field as soon as input in base field.Kindly help

```
function curr(){
  // some variables

  var baseCurrency = 'USD';

  var baseNumber = 1;

  var targetCurrency = 'INR';

  var targetNumber;

  var url;

  currencyConverter(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  // get base currency value

  $("#base").change(function () {
    // base currency

    baseCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)


  });

  // get base currency number

  $("#baseNumber").change(function(){

    // base number

    baseNumber = $(this).val()

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  })

  // get target currency value

  $("#target").change(function () {
    // target currency

    targetCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  });

  // get target currency number

  $("#targetNumber").change(function(){

    // target number

    targetNumber = $(this).val()

    // call currencyConverter function

    currencyConverter2(baseCurrency,baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)

  })


  // function to convert BaseCurrency to TargetCurrency

  function currencyConverter(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)
  {
      // api url

      url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols="+targetCurrency+"&base="+baseCurrency

      // make a get request to api

    

      $.get(url,function(data){
          console.log(data.rates)

          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.rates)) {
            
            var result = value * baseNumber

           $("#targetNumber").val(result)

          }
          console.log(`data.rates.${targetCurrency}`)
      })
  }

  function currencyConverter2(baseCurrency, baseNumber,targetCurrency,targetNumber)
  {
      // api url

      url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols="+baseCurrency+"&base="+targetCurrency

      // make a get request to api

      $.get(url,function(data){
          console.log(data.rates)

          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.rates)) {

            console.log(value)
            
            var result = value * targetNumber

           $("#baseNumber").val(result)

          }
          console.log(`data.rates.${targetCurrency}`)
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue in my project when i was building historical exchange rates  [currency converter](https://currencyfreaks.com/historical/exchange-rates) You can do same like this code below by using onkeyup event in your input html tag. hope it'll help you a lot.

```js
var amountBTC = document.getElementById("amountBTC");
var amountUSD = document.getElementById("amountUSD");
var amountNGN = document.getElementById("amountNGN");

var currentRateUSD = 1.0;
var currentRateNGN = 385.69;
var currentRateBTC = 0.000094; 


function convertAmount(currency) {


    var x = document.getElementById("selection").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("selection").options;

    if(y[x].text == "Sell"){

        var BTC = parseFloat(currentRateBTC);
        var NGN = parseFloat(currentRateNGN);
        var USD = parseFloat(currentRateUSD);



        fx.base = "USD";
        fx.rates = {
            "BTC" : BTC,
            "NGN" : NGN,
            "USD" : USD
        }

        if (currency == "BTC"){
            amountUSD.value = fx.convert(amountBTC.value, {from: "BTC", to: "USD"});
            amountNGN.value = fx.convert(amountBTC.value, {from: "BTC", to: "NGN"});
        }else if (currency == "USD"){
            amountBTC.value = fx.convert(amountUSD.value, {from: "USD", to: "BTC"});
            amountNGN.value = fx.convert(amountUSD.value, {from: "USD", to: "NGN"});
        }else if (currency == "NGN"){
            amountUSD.value = fx.convert(amountNGN.value, {from: "NGN", to: "USD"});
            amountBTC.value = fx.convert(amountNGN.value, {from: "NGN", to: "BTC"});
        }

    }else if(y[x].text == "Buy"){

        var BTC = parseFloat(currentRateBTC);
        var NGN = parseFloat(currentRateNGN);
        var USD = parseFloat(currentRateUSD);


        fx.base = "USD";
        fx.rates = {
            "BTC" : BTC,
            "NGN" : NGN,
            "USD" : USD
        }

        if (currency == "BTC"){
            amountUSD.value = fx.convert(amountBTC.value, {from: "BTC", to: "USD"});
            amountNGN.value = fx.convert(amountBTC.value, {from: "BTC", to: "NGN"});
        }else if (currency == "USD"){
            amountBTC.value = fx.convert(amountUSD.value, {from: "USD", to: "BTC"});
            amountNGN.value = fx.convert(amountUSD.value, {from: "USD", to: "NGN"});
        }else if (currency == "NGN"){
            amountUSD.value = fx.convert(amountNGN.value, {from: "NGN", to: "USD"});
            amountBTC.value = fx.convert(amountNGN.value, {from: "NGN", to: "BTC"});
        }
    }

}

function convertAmountToBTC_USD_NGN(from, to, amount) {
    var convertedAmount = (to/from)*amount;
    return convertedAmount;
}

function calculatePercent(percent, num){
    return (percent / 100) * num;
}


(function(root, undefined) {

    var fx = function(obj) {
        return new fxWrapper(obj);
    };


    fx.version = '0.2';


    var fxSetup = root.fxSetup || {
        rates : {},
        base : ""
    };

    fx.rates = fxSetup.rates;

    fx.base = fxSetup.base;

    fx.settings = {
        from : fxSetup.from || fx.base,
        to : fxSetup.to || fx.base
    };


    var convert = fx.convert = function(val, opts) {

        if (typeof val === 'object' && val.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i< val.length; i++ ) {
                val[i] = convert(val[i], opts);
            }
            return val;
        }


        opts = opts || {};

        if( !opts.from ) opts.from = fx.settings.from;
        if( !opts.to ) opts.to = fx.settings.to;

        return val * getRate( opts.to, opts.from );
    };

    var getRate = function(to, from) {

        var rates = fx.rates;

        rates[fx.base] = 1;

        if ( !rates[to] || !rates[from] ) throw "fx error";

        if ( from === fx.base ) {
            return rates[to];
        }

        if ( to === fx.base ) {
            return 1 / rates[from];
        }


        return rates[to] * (1 / rates[from]);
    };


    var fxWrapper = function(val) {

        if ( typeof val === "string" ) {
            this._v = parseFloat(val.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, ""));
            this._fx = val.replace(/([^A-Za-z])/g, "");
        } else {
            this._v = val;
        }
    };

    var fxProto = fx.prototype = fxWrapper.prototype;

    fxProto.convert = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.unshift(this._v);
        return convert.apply(fx, args);
    };

    fxProto.from = function(currency) {
        var wrapped = fx(convert(this._v, {from: currency, to: fx.base}));
        wrapped._fx = fx.base;
        return wrapped;
    };

    fxProto.to = function(currency) {
        return convert(this._v, {from: this._fx ? this._fx : fx.settings.from, to: currency});
    };


    if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
            exports = module.exports = fx;
        }
        exports.fx = fx;
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

        define([], function() {
            return fx;
        });
    } else {

        fx.noConflict = (function(previousFx) {
            return function() {

                root.fx = previousFx;

                fx.noConflict = undefined;

                return fx;
            };
        })(root.fx);

        root['fx'] = fx;
    }

}(this));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
<body>
            
     <div class="container">
    <div class="content-area">

        <article id="post-4007" class="post-4007 page type-page status-publish hentry">

    <div class="entry-content">
                    
    <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">
                        
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                        <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f2650-p4007-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response" aria-live="polite"></div>
<form method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<p><label> Buy or Sell (required) <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sellorbuy"><select id="selection" name="Buy-or-Sell" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Sell">Sell</option><option value="Buy">Buy</option></select></span></label></p>

<p><label> Amount in USD <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap AmounttoPayinUSD">
    <input type="number" name="Amount-in-USD" id="amountUSD" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number" aria-invalid="false" onkeyup="convertAmount('USD')" />
</span> </label></p>
<p><label> Amount  in Naira <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap AmounttoPayinNaira">
    <input type="number" name="Amount-in-Naira" id="amountNGN" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number" aria-invalid="false" onkeyup="convertAmount('NGN')" />
</span> </label></p>
<p><label> Amount in Bitcoin <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap BuyingAmountBITCOIN">
    <input type="text" name="Amount-in-Bitcoin" id="amountBTC" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" onkeyup="convertAmount('BTC')" />
</span></label></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none" aria-hidden="true"></div></form></div>        </div>
    </div>
</div>    </div>

                    </div>
    
</article>
    </div>

    </div> <!--.container-->
    </div> <!--#main-->
    </div> <!--.content_wrapper-->

        </div> <!--#wrapper-->

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/money.js/0.2.0/money.min.js?ver=0.2.0'></script>

<script src="./converter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onKeyPress Event for calling a function whenever a key is pressed and for that, you can change your onBlur function to this.

```
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="baseNumber" value="1" onkeypress="curr()">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code is in curr() - if you don't call curr() function somewhere it's not binding event to your elements, that why it's not working.

If you need to wrap your code inside function you can use an anonymous function like this:

```
(function() {
    // your code
})();
```

Or just make a call curr() function anywhere.